# Composer: Command Not Found on Mac

Tags: composer-php, twilio

I have installed Composer as per the instructions [command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnwG2.png)

After installing I get the prompt that Composer is successfully installed but when I go to check the version it gives me error "Composer: Command Not Found"

Comment: A link to an image of your result is not recommended. Can you please post the "command not found" directly to this question (the link can be kept as it is supplementary)

Answer (score 7):

I have been looking how to fix this issue and I had to read and understand little bit and the environment variables on MAC.

I understand the issue looks simple but it will get over complicated if you didn't understand how to install composer probably.

**Solution 1**

I found this solution here: https://duvien.com/blog/installing-composer-mac-osx

Open a terminal and navigate to your user directory, ie cd /User//
Run this command shown below to download Composer. This will create a Phar (PHP Archive) file called composer.phar:

```
 curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Now we move composer.phar file to a directory

```
  sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/
```

We want to run Composer with having to be root al the time, so we need to change the permissions:

```
 sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

Next, we need to let Bash know where to execute Composer:

```
 nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this line below to bash_profile and save

alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
and then run this command:

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally, run: 
    composer --version

**Solution 2:**

I understand that the first command you will find online when you try to google this issue would be

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

But actually this is the main terminal installation but sometimes I wanted to manually install the composer, so this 2nd solution about manually installing the composer in specific directory

First of all you need to understand where are you now on the terminal 
use 
   pwd 
and then install composer manually using the following commands

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') ==='baf1608c33254d00611ac1705c1d9958c817a1a33bce370c0595974b342601bd80b92a3f46067da89e3b06bff421f182') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; 
unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

[image: installing the commands lines]

to use it on that case you will read on the terminal to use this composer installation use 
      Use it: php composer.phar

so just write
php composer.phar

and it should be working.... one more thing, during this installation you can install the composer to specific directory / project folder... in that case you can use a flag with command No.4 to tell the terminal to install the composer in specific  directory...this flag is --install-dir=your-directory-path

[image: install composer in direcoty]

and you will the terminal this time after installing composer asking you to use the following path to call the composer

```
Use it: php /Users/muatafa/composer.phar
```

if you want to read more about this issue, I think you must read the composer documentation how to install it>>> https://getcomposer.org/download/

that's how I solved my current issue... if you still have any issues comment on this replay & Hopefully we can figure it out!

Comment: First option helped so much. thx.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. "composer require something" works if installed in global and not locally.

If you install composer locally you'll then install dependencies using "php composer.phar require nameofyoudependency"

To install globally open a terminal to install as mentionned on the composer website. Then run "sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer"

Now you can use "composer" directly to install dependencies like => "composer require something/sdk"

Answer (score 0):

the composer you installed is still named **/usr/local/bin/composer.phar** - look in the second yellow/brownish line in your output. Just rename it to just composer

Comment: I already have a file in the same location that is "composer" as its file name https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2ufkhz5jx82s57/Screen%20Shot%202018-07-31%20at%207.00.29%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: no your screenshot is showing your home directory (note the tilde). just rename the file under /usr/local/bin/composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer

Answer (score 0):

Your composer command is not set to path, use

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Thanks Erisan, I am a newbie. not sure "not set to path mean"? I have 3 composer files in my root path "composer, composer-setup.php and composer.phar" do I go to my root path in terminal and type "sudo export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"?  that just gives me the error "sudo: export: command not found
yamirs-mac-pro:~ yamirbhatt$ "

Comment: @yamirb just type `sudo` then after authenticating with your root password, type `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, After installing composer using the command line on their website. I forgot to put composer.phar into a directory on my PATH, so it can simply be called from any directory (Global install). and then I ran this command "sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer" and it was resolved

Answer (score -1):

I figured out. in place of "composer require twilio/sdk" I needed to use

"composer.phar require twilio/sdk" since I am on mac. It worked

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you provide steps??